# jquery and RESTful wcf service

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I have xcrated a RESTful wcf service in vs2012. I can access this sservice frfom web brovsers. my Interface file is so:

```
namespace RestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "xml/{id}"
            )]
        string XMLData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}"
            )]
        string JSONData(string id);

    }
}
```

and my configuration file is that :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I'm running my service with ctr+F5 it gives me that url `localhost:50046/RestServiceImpl.svc`

and when I write to web browser that code I can access my service and a response comes:

code is`//localhost:50046/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/123`
response is `{"JSONDataResult":"you requested product 123"}`

Now my problem is that, I will be accessing that service from my html code. And I will be sending a data to service and having a response from that service. My simple jquery code is :

```
$("input:#giris").click(function(){
    function GetCategoriesJson() {

        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"GET",
            url:"localhost:50046/RestServiceImpl.svc",
            data:"{123}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json/{123}", 
            success: OnSuccessJson, 
            error: OnErrorJson
        });
        function OnSuccessJson(data, status) {
            alert("basarili")
        }
        function OnErrorJson(data, status) {
            alert("Exception");
        }
        }   
    });
```

What I must do and what I must write to type, url, data, contentype, datatype etc. Please help I've been working for a few days

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get when calling it from your client?

Since it's WCF i guess its a config matter, try this in you .config file.

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" 
    automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" 
    defaultOutgoingResponseFormat ="Json" />
```

Here is a good example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call

Comment: Try to capture the http traffic from the client, with for eg Fiddler, to how the request looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you try this:-

In ajax call change url to this

`url:"localhost:50046/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/123"`